# How to pass ternary that return a widget in Flutter

Tags: date, flutter, time, conditional-statements, ternary

Hi I would like to make a condition using ternary inside my widget... but I didn't able to pass it... the error says that `type '()=>Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'` and here is the code

```
DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now()) =="05:12:01"
?
// the error starts from here since I have 2 commands (setState and widget Text) inside function
() {
setState(() {
  fail = true;
  _imageFile = null;
});
Text('Time is up');
}
: Text("Success")
```

what should I do to get `Text('Time is up');` and

```
setState(() {
  fail = true;
  _imageFile = null;
});
```

is that bad idea to wrap it inside function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return someCondition ? SomeWidget() : OtherWidget();//someCondition is a bool defined in your class
}
```

in the code you provided you should put an if statement you can't put statements in a conditional expression

Comment: it works after I wrap it inside Widget like your code :D thank you for your help